# Could not fetch snmp values of a windows machine from linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, snmp, access-control, net-snmp

I have a windows machine and linux machine in the same network. Both the machines are ping-able to each other.

I have enabled default SNMP and also installed Net-SNMP in the WINDOWS machine and have configured it properly.

Firewall on windows machine are turned OFF.

I tried to do `snmpwalk` in windows machine itself. And I got the results for the query.

When I tried to do the same snmpwalk from linux machine, I get an error like below,

`Timeout: No Response from 192.168.0.117`

Following is the `snmpd.conf` file contents.

```
###########################################################################
#
# snmpd.conf
#
#   - created by the snmpconf configuration program
#
###########################################################################
# SECTION: Access Control Setup
#
#   This section defines who is allowed to talk to your running
#   snmp agent.

# rocommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-only access community name
#   arguments:  community [default|hostname|network/bits] [oid]

rocommunity  public

# rwcommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-write access community name
#   arguments:  community [default|hostname|network/bits] [oid]

rocommunity  private
```

What is going wrong in my process? Why am I not being able to query the windows-snmp details from a remote Linux machine?

Comment: What are the specific command on each side? ping response does not means port 161 is reachable cause it could be listening on loopback (127.0.0.1) at win box. Use the same IP at both sides, localhost could be mapped to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer for this problem.

To enable snmp to respond for queries from remote machines, a settings needs to be enabled in

**Run** (windows key+r) -> **services.msc** -> **'Enter'**

Services window will open, go to **SNMP services** -> **Right click** -> **Properties**

SNMP service properties window will open.

Go to **Security** tab in that window. And enable "**Accept SNMP packets from any host**" (or) If you only only to respond to specific host, Add its IP address below it in the next option.